# Typing dict mixin class with Mypy

Tags: python, dictionary, multiple-inheritance, mixins, mypy

I'm trying to write a small mixin class to somewhat bridge Set and MutableMapping types: I want the mapping types to have ability to receive some objects (bytes), hash them, and store them, so they are accessible by that hash.

Here's a working version of mixing this class with standard `dict`:

```py
from hashlib import blake2b

class HashingMixin:
    def add(self, content):
        digest = blake2b(content).hexdigest()
        self[digest] = content

class HashingDict(dict, HashingMixin):
    pass
```

However I can't figure out how to add type annotations.

From https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1996 it seems the mixin has to subclass `abc.ABC` and `abc.abstractmethod`-define all the methods it expects to call, so here's my shot:

```py
import abc
from hashlib import blake2b
from typing import Dict

class HashingMixin(abc.ABC):
    def add(self, content: bytes) -> None:
        digest = blake2b(content).hexdigest()
        self[digest] = content

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> bytes:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, content: bytes) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError


class HashingDict(Dict[str, bytes], HashingMixin):
    pass
```

Then Mypy complains about the `HashingDict` definition:

```
error: Definition of "__getitem__" in base class "dict" is incompatible with definition in base class "HashingMixin"
error: Definition of "__setitem__" in base class "dict" is incompatible with definition in base class "HashingMixin"
error: Definition of "__setitem__" in base class "MutableMapping" is incompatible with definition in base class "HashingMixin"
error: Definition of "__getitem__" in base class "Mapping" is incompatible with definition in base class "HashingMixin"
```

Revealing types with:

```
reveal_type(HashingMixin.__getitem__)
reveal_type(HashingDict.__getitem__)
```

yields:

```
error: Revealed type is 'def (coup.content.HashingMixin, builtins.str) -> builtins.bytes'
error: Revealed type is 'def (builtins.dict[_KT`1, _VT`2], _KT`1) -> _VT`2'
```

I don't know what is wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in mypy -- see [this TODO](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/checker.py#L1646) in the code mypy uses to analyze the MRO of classes using multiple inheritance. In short, mypy is incorrectly completing ignoring that you've parameterized `Dict` with concrete values, and is instead analyzing the code as if you were using `Dict`.

I believe https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5973 is probably the most relevant issue in the issue tracker: the root cause is the same.

Until that bug is fixed, you can suppress the errors mypy is generating on that line by adding a `# type: ignore` to whatever line has the errors. So in your case, you could do the following:

```py
import abc
from hashlib import blake2b
from typing import Dict

class HashingMixin(abc.ABC):
    def add(self, content: bytes) -> None:
        digest = blake2b(content).hexdigest()
        self[digest] = content

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> bytes:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, content: bytes) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError


class HashingDict(Dict[str, bytes], HashingMixin):  # type: ignore
    pass
```

If you decide to take this approach, I recommend also leaving an additional comment documenting why you're suppressing those errors and running mypy with the `--warn-unused-ignores` flag.

The former is for the benefit of any future readers of your code; the latter will make mypy report a warning whenever it encounters a `# type: ignore` that is not actually suppressing any errors and so can safely be deleted.

(And of course, you can always take a stab at contributing a fix yourself!)

Comment: hmm the issue is fixed and your mypy source link is broken (because you linked to master!)